# DataTables warning (table id = 'IDTableName'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Jquery Datatable in ASP.NET, and UpdatePanel (scriptManager) .
I have the next below error:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'tbVerificationApplicant'): Cannot
>   reinitialise DataTable.
>
> To retrieve the Datatables object for this table, pass no argument or
>   see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

This is the Jquery file to create the table:

```
function DatatablesExec() { 
        $('#tbVerificationApplicant').dataTable({
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            'sAjaxSource': 'listVerificationData.ashx?ddlStatusValue=' + $("#ddlStatusClient option:selected").text(),
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                $('#tbVerificationApplicant tbody tr').click(function () {
                    var hRef = $("td:eq(0)", this).text();
                    document.location.href = 'frm_VerifyIdentity.aspx?ID=' + hRef;
                });
            }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Initialise the DataTable */

        DatatablesExec()

});
```

But, to avoid that the table desapear after I changed the dropdownlist, I added the next below code in the code behind in the web form.

```
protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "_function_dummyname", "<script type='text/javascript'>DatatablesExec();</script>", false);
    }
}
```

It's working well, but at the begining appear a pop up with this error.

Thi is part of the web form:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlStatusClient" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table id="tbVerificationApplicant" class="display">
                <thead>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your page loads ,your function `DatatablesExec()` is executed twice: once in code-behind `Page_Prerender` and once in `$(document).ready` function.

The error means you are trying to make a table a Datatable, when it infact is already a Datatable.

You will have to rethink your design here.

Why is it neccessary to RegisterStartupScript in PreRender?

Try removing either one of the two `DatatablesExec()` and your problem should dissapear!

Comment: Hi. I used the RegisterStartupScript in PreRender because I'm using the  UpdatePanel control, and when I click on the dropdownlist, the table desapear. That why, if I remove it, this will no work anymore. And I need to make a reference from the RegisterStartupScript in PreRender to the function in Jquery. Do you know how can I modify it?

Comment: I added "bDestroy": true in the function and is working, the error desapear, but the layout in the first load is lossing. Do you know why?

Comment: Try running fnDestroy() on your table before initialising it again

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! This was driving me nuts! Funny fact: I knew I was calling it twice!

Answer (score 5):

This drove me nuts, too, so I thought I'd add the solution that worked for me.

If you're sending any Ajax requests that respond in some element of your table, in your table configuration you'll need to set

```
bRetrieve: true
```

[SUVASH'S BLOG explains:](http://suvashblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/datatables-warningtable-id-example-cannot-reinitialise-data-table/)

> There is an another scenario ,say you send more than one ajax request
>   which response will access same table in same template then we will
>   get error also.In this case fnDestroy method doesn’t work properly
>   because you don’t know which response comes first or later.Then you
>   have to set bRetrieve TRUE in data table configuration.That’s it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem too i read different threads about solving this but no luck.
But at the end i have initialized datatable in jquery window load method

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#example").DataTable();
});
```

instead of jquery's document ready method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#example").DataTable();
});
```

and miracle happens :) .. 
Hope it helps you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone i just want to add something in this case, i also experience it and also search for the solution for this problem but now i found the answer rather than using bDestroy always check your referencing id of the datatable in my case if you already use this

```
$('#dtAddParticipantList').dataTable
```

and your other table also use this

```
$('#dtAddParticipantList').dataTable
```

change it to something different

```
var oTable = $('#dtParticipantList').dataTable({ 
 //some code stuffs
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `destory: true` to your dataTable configuration:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
  destory: true,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('#example').dataTable().fnClearTable();
> $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();